# Facetime group/conference call integration in swift4

Tags: facetime

I could see apple doc talks about integration URL scheme for one on one call [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/FacetimeLinks/FacetimeLinks.html).

But we have a requirement to initiate a group call from our app. From ios 12.1.4 facetime group call feature has been introduced, but not finding any APIs to invoke facetime app with multiple participants.

Does anyone attempt this?